# How to control privileges, runtime, and memory usages of a child process?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, subprocess, privileges

I need to spawn a child process from python with only output privilege (absolutely NO access to file system, network, OS, input etc). It needs to terminate after the specified amount of time and only use the specified amount of memory. How can I accomplish that?

This will run in a Linux container so any OS/Linux-based solution(or system calls) are also welcome. (No constraint on the distro; whatever works)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a container to define your client, I think the best idea would be to create a user in the client Dockerfile with limited privileges and  make that user start the process.